# Spacing between brace and comment

Tags: c, comments, indentation, gnu-indent

Given the file *alfa.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { // this is a comment
  puts("hello world");
}
```

I can format it with GNU Indent like so:

```
$ indent -st alfa.c
#include <stdio.h>
int
main ()
{                               // this is a comment
  puts ("hello world");
}
```

However the comment is now way off to the right. I did try adding an option:

```
$ indent -st -c0 alfa.c
#include <stdio.h>
int
main ()
{       // this is a comment
  puts ("hello world");
}
```

but this is still not quite right. Can Indent be invoked such a way that the
comment starts after only 1 or 2 spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indent -c0 -nut -ts2`

This will change all your tabs to spaces.

the -c0 removes indentation for comments after code (so this will affect all comments).

edit: reduced the spaces in a tab

Answer (score 0):

It is putting the comment one tab after the brace.  To get around that, set the tab size, indent and replace tabs with spaces.  Say we want the standard indent to be 3 spaces

```
indent -st -c0 -i3 -ts3 -nut alfa.c
```